# Difference between Material-Ui and Material-Ui-Next

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, npm-package

I am trying to add Material-Ui React components in my project and I'm confused with these 2 websites / libraries.

Material-Ui-Next -> https://material-ui-next.com/

Material-Ui -> http://www.material-ui.com

Both websites have a link to Github - https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui

Are they same or different?  Both of them are using `import {something} from 'material-ui/xxx'` to import the components.

I'm confused and which one I should learn/use in my project. Can you suggest?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Material-UI Next is in pre-release, so you can expect possible breaking changes with each new release. But it is simply version 2 of Material-UI, it has quite a bit of improvements over the previous version.

For example, you can compare the `Drawer` api of [Material-UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/drawer) and [Material-UI Next](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/drawers/).

I'd recommend reading the [Roadmap](https://material-ui-next.com/discover-more/roadmap/), they explain why they decided to start from the ground up with Material-UI Next. Mainly,

> Material-UI was started 3 years ago. The ecosystem has evolved a lot
>   since then, we have also learned a lot. @nathanmarks started an
>   ambitious task, rebuilding Material-UI from the ground-up taking
>   advantage of this knowledge to address long-standing issues.

Material-UI Next is what will continue to be developed moving forward, so I'd personally go with that.

Comment: Plus the developers of the library recommend to use the Next version as it is so much easier to update, even breaking changes.

Comment: @sme I believe the difference between both has been removed. Both links http://www.material-ui.com and https://material-ui-next.com end up in the same site https://material-ui.com